# Nodejs mysqldump on Server

Tags: mysql, node.js, child-process, dump

I've attempted to dump  (copy and paste) a database on server with nodejs (express).

OS: Ubuntu 18

Code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
create_dump = (user, pass, db_main_name, copy_name_withoutextension) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(`mysqldump -u ${user} -p${pass} ${db_main_name} > /${copy_name_withoutextension}.sql`, (err, out) => {
            if (err)reject(err)
            resolve(out)
        });

    });
```

**Error: Command failed**:
*'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

it (*mysqldump*) works with command line perfectly and the problem is just in nodejs *'child_process'*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey,
1. do you have mySQL running?.
2. I see that there is no space between -p and ${pass} in your code above. Currently, it is:  `-p${pass}` I modified that with space and it asks me to enter a password.
3.

Comment: Hi, 1. Yes I have , because it works by cmd (with ssh ). 2. I've tested and without space with commandline works (not asks again to enter password)

Comment: @s.d.fard I copied your exact same code, changed the database name and the creds, then ran it and it just worked fine! However, am using a Linux machine, I guess you're using Windows?! I wouldn't say this is a nodejs issue since it does its job which is executing a shell command and reporting back the result (the error)! Have you looked at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html)?

Comment: @MAS Thanks for link! was because of ENV Variables :-)

Answer (score 0):

It was the Environmental Variables Problem and was because of differences between Windows and Linux.